# Convert Wand image to GTK image

Tags: gtk3, wand, pyobject

Context: Debian 11, Python 3.9.2, PyObject GTK 3.0, WAND 0.6.5

I currently use PIL and to load image in GTK I do:

```
data = pil_img.tobytes()
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(data,  ...)
```

I want to do the same thing with WAND and have tried `data = wand_img.make_blob()` but it doesn't work, GTK answers "*constructor returned NULL*"

Thankfully using numpy works: `data = numpy.array(wand_img).tobytes()`

So what? The problem is that going through numpy is very slow, causing me to lose 400 ms compared with PIL, which makes the application much less responsive.

Is there a way to convert WAND image to bytes without using numpy ?